# How to insert background and top image in screen - Video API

Tags: opentok

I'm using Video API to live streaming events, but I found a problem and didn't find the answer in documentation.

For custom layouts: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/broadcast/live-streaming/#custom-layouts

How can I insert background image and top images? Like this one: https://d.pr/free/i/DkIplo

Thanks!